# Generating automatic NodeIDs in our own namespace

Tags: client, opc-ua, open62541

For creating a new node from client (any type , does not matter), I used the below function.

```
UA_NodeId new_node_id;
.....some code...
UA_Client_addVariableNode(m_client,
                          UA_NODEID_NULL,
                          parent_node_id,
                          UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_ORGANIZES),
                          UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(my_namespace_idx, "b"),
                          UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_BASEDATAVARIABLETYPE),
                          v_attr,
                          &new_node_id);
```

So, the function automatically creates a new node id for me, so that I don not have to bother about finding a new node id, when I create new nodes dynamically( this is the case in my application)
The `new_node_id` is generated in the `namespace = 0`. The question is, Is there a way to do the same my own namespace, instead of `namespace = 0`?

Comment: What happens when you use `my_namespace_idx` instead of `0` upon node ID creation?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create the nodes in your own namespace index.

- Namespace index 0 is reserved for nodes in the information model that
  are defined by the core OPC UA specification and having the URI as
  http://opcfoundation.org/UA
- Namespace index 1 is for the nodes that are instances that
  would not belong to a specific information model
- You can create **your custom namespace index** within the range **2
  to 255**, that is nodes belonging to use-case specific information
  models

For e.g. if you wish to assign a numeric node id for your custom node, you can assign the custom Namespace Index as the first argument and the numeric NodeId as the second argument to the UA_NODEID_NUMERIC function

```
UA_NodeId new_node_id = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(2, 1001);
```

If you would like to try with other types of Node IDs, you can try using these functions:

```
+======================+=================+===========================================================================+
|    Function Name     | Identifier Type |                                Description                                |
+======================+=================+===========================================================================+
| UA_NODEID_NUMERIC    | Numeric         | Assign numeric type NodeId can be in the range of 0 to 65535              |
+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| UA_NODEID_STRING     | String          | Assign string type NodeId can have up to 4096 characters                  |
+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| UA_NODEID_GUID       | GUID            | Assign GUID type NodeId which is a 128 but globally unique identifier     |
+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| UA_NODEID_BYTESTRING | Byte String     | Assign the namespace specific bytestring NodeId can have up to 4096 bytes |
+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can also refer to the documentation available here: https://open62541.org/doc/current/

If you are looking for more hands-on information of open62541 stack, you can also check out the paid online course: Practical introduction to OPC UA – code walk-through and examples in this course use the open62541 stack: https://opcfoundation.org/products/view/practical-introduction-to-opc-ua-part-i